# Deploy additional artefacts to Nexus 2 using Maven

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a Java project that is built using Maven and deployed to Nexus 2.

E.g. release builds are deployed to:

```
repositories/releases/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.1.0
repositories/releases/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.2.0
```

Snapshot builds are deployed to:

```
repositories/snapshots/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
repositories/snapshots/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

During the deploy phase I would like to deploy some additional artefacts to Nexus to the following repository, with the folder depending on whether the build is a release or a snapshot.

```
repositories/test/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.1.0/some-folder
repositories/test/com/my-company/a/b/c/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/some-folder
```

From reading around on this subject it looks like I can use the deploy plugin to achieve this but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What kind of purpose does it have to deploy to supplemental repositories? Apart from that folders can't be deployed to a repository manager only artifacts (jar, war, ear, zip, tar.gz etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking in "folders" is a bit misleading. You deploy to nexus using groupId, artifactId, version, packaging and classifier. Nexus translates this to a folder structure, but you cannot create arbitrary folders in Nexus.

If you want to deploy additional artifacts, this is possible using the `deploy:deploy-file` goal, but you have to give them Maven coordinates (groupId, artifactId,...) not a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has five componentes of it's artifact coordinates (a.k.a. GAV (short for `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`). These artifact coordinates are:

- `groupId`
- `artifactId`
- `version`
- `type`
- `classifier`

Based on these coordinates Maven constructs paths for you.

For example for:

- `groupId` : `com.foo`
- `artifactId` : `bar`
- `version` : `1.0`
- `type` : `jar`
- `classifier`: `jdk12`

It will produce a path such as:

```
com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0-jdk12.jar
```

If there is no `classifier`, it will create just:

```
com/foo/bar/1.0/bar-1.0.jar
```

What you're trying to do does not fit in the artifact coordinates supported by Maven and is, therefore, incorrect.